# Cookie grabber in Php or javascript

Tags: php, javascript

I want to make a scrip through which i can grab the visitors cookis and store it in the txt file.can it be possible if so then help me.Doesn't matter it should be in php or javascript.

Comment: I want... And I've tried < *put content here* >

Comment: How can it not matter whether it is in JS or PHP? One runs at the client and the other at the server. Where do you want to create the text file?

Comment: possible yes, what have you tried?

Comment: @DarkXphenomenon i want to store the txt in my Pc's any folder

Comment: @GeoPhoenix i have'nt tried anything ..first just getting the concept then will furbish

Comment: In your PC. Is it acting as the client or the server? If you want to locally aggregate cookies, use a batch/shell script, not PHP or JS

Comment: @DarkXphenomenon ok..if i want o store on my server file  then what??

Comment: Php.. Sandermangel's solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to use PHP for that to write the cookie content to the server.

```
$cookieContent = "";
foreach (array_keys($_COOKIES) as $ckey) {
    $cookieContent = $ckey . ": " . filter_input(INPUT_COOKIE, $ckey, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING) . "\n"; 
}

file_put_contents('path/to/cookie_store_file.txt', $cookieContent."\n\n", FILE_APPEND);
```

This wil write the cookies belonging to your site from each user to the same text file on the server.

Comment: ok ..but will it work for the visitor of my website.

Comment: beacuse...catching users cookie is easy..but of visitor it is typical he is unknown

Comment: It's your website right? and you want to store the cookies of all your visitors?

Comment: for this the script which you have written is right??

Comment: yes, it will catch all the visitors cookies that have been set by your site

Comment: ok..one last thing to ask..is i m a medical student so dont ahve programming studies..but i work on php javascript sql html css jquery ajax and now want to work in OOP php so any site to learn it easily because it is typicall for me

Comment: Im not sure what your question is but for anything about PHP i'd check php.net

Comment: ok.. i just want to learn OOP progrmaming in php ..it seems difficult to me so any solution

Comment: Get an o'reilly book about php, thats always a good start

Answer (score 1):

in php cookies are stored in the $_COOKIE variable.. or $_REQUEST.

```
//save cookies to a file:
$ser=serialize($_COOKIE);
file_put_contents("cookies.txt", $ser);

//read cookies back from file:
$cookies= unserialize( file_get_contents("cookies.txt"));
```

Comment: ok...but will it catch the cookie of a visiotr

Comment: yes, you don't need javascript enabled.. but of course, it will only catch the cookies for YOUR site (if you set any), you can't "catch" / download all the cookies for any site, that would be a security flaw.

Comment: yes.i was thinking this..it would not be able to catch any ohter site cookies despite of mine one's.but what do you think about an iframe on others website,,,:)